# How to set different item in grid view?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, layout

I have an app in which I have two views namely image view and text view and have two type of data like string and textdrawable and int.What i want to set one textdrawable in image view, and on int image view and textview will remain same. How do i do that

code:-

```
LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dash_board_fragment_one_items, null);

    TextView name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_android);
    CircleImageView icon=(CircleImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
    name.setText(android.get(position).getAndroid_version_name());
    icon.setImageDrawable(android.get(position).getAndroid_image_url());
    return convertView;
```

and here is the code of datamodel

```
  private String android_version_name;
private TextDrawable android_image_url;
private int img;

public String getAndroid_version_name() {
    return android_version_name;
}

public void setAndroid_version_name(String android_version_name) {
    this.android_version_name = android_version_name;
}

public TextDrawable getAndroid_image_url() {
    return android_image_url;
}

public void setAndroid_image_url(TextDrawable android_image_url) {
    this.android_image_url = android_image_url;
}

public int getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(int img) {
    this.img = img;
}
}
```

Comment: What will you get in `img` every time?

Comment: You have a app with two views ? Too confusing . Edit your question right away with proper explanation of problem.

Answer (score 0):

set default value of `img` int variable to -1

```
private int img=-1;
```

Now in `getView` method

```
if(android.get(position).getImg()==-1)
{
icon.setImageDrawable(android.get(position).getAndroid_image_url());
}
else
{
icon.setImageResource(android.get(position).getImg());
}
```

keep your img variable value to -1 if you don't have resource file